# My doctor gave me this IQ test - what's your diagnosis?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, pattern

I got a lot of trouble focusing lately, so I went to my doctor just to make sure nothing was wrong.  He didn't say anything when I explained my issues, and he just handed me an IQ test instead of a complete diagnosis, which I find kinda weird...

Anyway, I thought it could be a great idea to share it with you guys so we could compare our scores!

***Question 1***

[image: iq 1]

***Question 3***

[image: iq 3]

***Question 5***

[image: iq 5]

***Question 7***

[image: iq 7]

***Question 9***

[image: iq 9]

***Question 11***

[image: iq 11]

I think I managed to answer every question correctly! **So, there's nothing I should worry about, right?**

---

*Hint:*

> *Hint*

*Hint 2:*

> I solved all 12 questions of the test - and I can swear this is the exact test I have been given. I didn’t forget anything.

*Hint 3 (for question 9):*

> Following the exact same logic, here's what question 9 could've been:
>  [image: iq 5.5]

Comment: Perhaps it's a word using ABCD in the odd positions…

Comment: I mean, it's multiple choice, so it kind of makes sense. Or maybe the last one uses the letter in the shape.

Comment: Oh It certainly does  

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sup>***A complete solution**, explaining the overall puzzle mechanism, the solutions to the 12 questions - yes, 12... - and the final two-word answer phrase... Thanks to @samm82, @Alaiko, @TheFootprint, @Jack23 and @Prim3numbah for assistance or inspiration in their answers and comments.*</sup>

Your doctor suspects you have:

> **DOUBLE VISION**! This can be worked out by realising that each of the 'six' IQ test puzzles actually has **two solutions** - one for the series above the horizontal line (where the possible options are the images *below* the line), and one for the series below it (where the final question mark is missing and the possible options are the images *above* the line) - so really there are *double* that number (i.e. twelve)! In each case, a single letter is encoded by the solution image; once all are combined, the phrase 'DOUBLE VISION' will be spelled out in order.

**Question 1: (solved, by @Alaiko in comments)**

[image: Question 1]

> As pointed out by @Alaiko in a [comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124776/my-doctor-gave-me-this-iq-test-whats-your-diagnosis/124828?noredirect=1#comment346700_124828) on this post, the answer to this one is definitely the first option, because the black cells shaded in each of the four options given so far are all distinct, with no duplication. If the aim is to shade all cells in the 5x5 grid, the option that shows all of the so-far-unshaded ones is the first:
>
>  [image: Question 1 answer - D]
>
>  Considering the pattern of black squares, this resembles a letter '**D**' in shape.

**Question 2: (solved)**

> [image: Question 2]
>
>  Count the number of black squares in each image - the number decreases by 1 each time (10-9-8-7). Next, we need an image containing 6 black squares, which is the second one from the top line:
>
>  [image: Question 2 answer - O]
>
>  This resembles a letter '**O**' in shape.

**Question 3: (solved)**

[image: Question 3]

*(Solved independently of @pppp_prs but they have the right pattern here...)*

> Count the number of distinct enclosed areas in the image - the number decreases by 1 each time (4-3-2-1). Next, we need an image with 0 enclosed areas, which is the final option:
>
>  [image: Question 3 answer - U]
>
>  This resembles a letter '**U**' in shape.

**Question 4: (solved)**

> [image: Question 4]
>
>  Note that the boxes appear to resemble stylised versions of the letters Z, Q, W, U, all drawn in a way that can be done with a pen in a single series of strokes, without lifting the pen from the paper.
>
>  The answer to this one is the only one that resembles a letter and can be drawn without lifting a pen from the paper - the third option:
>
>  [image: Question 4 answer - B]
>
>  This resembles a letter '**B**' in shape.

**Question 5: (solved)**

[image: Question 5]

> The trick to this one is to realise that there is not just *one* arrow in each diagram, but *two* (something I could not see for a very long time) - because aside from the obvious arrowhead on one of the three hands in each image, the three hands themselves make one much bigger arrowhead between them:
>
>  [image: Question 5 - the large arrows indicated]
>
>  With this noted, now look at the directions that each of the small arrowheads point:
>
>  [image: Question 5 - the small arrows indicated]
>
>  Now we can see a pattern clearly: In each image, the bigger arrowhead points in the same direction that the small arrowhead did in the *previous* image. Therefore, we need to choose an option to come next in which the bigger arrowhead points in the south-west direction (i.e. the same as the small arrowhead in the final picture). This means the answer must be the fourth option:
>
>  [image: Question 5 answer - L]
>
>  This resembles a letter '**L**' in shape.

**Question 6: (solved)**

> [image: Question 6]
>
>  Note that all images in this set involve the arrow being on the small hand between the two long ones. There is only one such possibility among the remaining options - the third option:
>
>  [image: Question 6 answer - E]
>
>  This resembles a letter '**E**' in shape.

**Question 7: (solved by @TheFootprint, in comments)**

[image: Question 7]

> As pointed out by @TheFootprint in a [comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124776/my-doctor-gave-me-this-iq-test-whats-your-diagnosis/124828?noredirect=1#comment346712_124829), this sub-puzzle relies on spotting that the number of dots which change colour (from white to black, or black to white) between one initial state and the next is the same as the number of white dots in the initial state, as per the following diagram:
>
>  [image: Question 7 explained - counting white dots and subsequent changes]
>
>  Given that the fourth image in the series has 6 white dots, we thus need to choose an option that would mean 6 dots have changed colour - there is only one possibility, that being the fourth option:
>
>  [image: Question 7 answer - V]
>
>  This resembles a letter '**V**' in shape.

**Question 8: (solved)**

> [image: Question 8]
>
>  These shapes spell out in dots letters used as Roman numerals, in descending order of value: C (100), L (50), X (10), V (5). The next in the series is '**I**' (1), i.e. the first option:
>
>  [image: Question 8 answer - I]

**Question 9: (solved, by @Jack23)**

[image: Question 9]

> As found by @Jack23 in [their answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/124871/60644), this sub-puzzle requires us to count all the hexagon edges that do *not* border a shaded hexagonal cell (i.e. all the edges between two adjacent unshaded hexagons, and all the edges of unshaded hexagons which do not border any other cells at all. Then in each of the 4 images in this set, the numbered cell shows this total number of edges:
>
>  [image: Edges to count shaded in different colours]
>
>  Only one of the options also fulfils this pattern - the first image:
>
>  [image: Question 9 answer - S]
>
>  The number '19' held within it corresponds to '**S**' in A1Z26.

**Question 10: (solved)**

> [image: Question 10]
>
>  If (as prompted by @TheFootprint in [comments](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124776/my-doctor-gave-me-this-iq-test-whats-your-diagnosis#comment346818_124828)) we label the hexagonal cells with numbers from 1 to 7, top to bottom, left to right - like this:
>
>  [image: Numbered hexagonal cells, 1 to 7]
>
>  ...then in each of the 4 images in this set, the numbered cell shows the total produced by adding the values of all the other cells left unshaded in the image:
>
>  [image: Cells to sum shaded in red]
>
>  Only one of the options also fulfils this pattern - the second image:
>
>  [image: Question 10 answer - I - with red shading to illustrate the sum]
>
>  This contains the number '9'; by A1Z26 this value represents the letter '**I**'.

**Question 11: (solved, by @samm82 in comments)**

[image: Question 11]

> (As pointed out by @samm82 in a [comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124776/my-doctor-gave-me-this-iq-test-whats-your-diagnosis#comment346692_124822) on another answer...) Identify the shapes in the series: ANGLE, SQUARE, CIRCLE, TRIANGLE. Now note that the letter contained within each shape is the *n*th letter of the shape's name, where '*n*' is the number of sides it has: A(N)GLE, SQU(A)RE, (C)IRCLE, TR(I)ANGLE. The only one of the options that also fulfils this pattern is the hexagonal one:
>
>  [image: Question 11 answer - O]
>
>  This is a 6-sided HEXAG(O)N containing a letter '**O**'.

**Question 12: (solved)**

> [image: Question 12]
>
>  Focus only on the letters contained within each shape: J-A-S-O. These are the initial letters of four consecutive months of the year: (J)uly, (A)ugust, (S)eptember, (O)ctober. Next in this sequence would be (**N**)ovember, given by the first option:
>
>  [image: Question 12 answer - N]

Put the answers to all these questions together, and the answer is spelled out in front of your eyes:

> **DOUBLE VISION**!

Comment: Nicely done! rot13(Sbe dhrfgvba 1, V guvax gur ernfba jul 'Q' vf gur nafjre vf orpnhfr lbh arrq gb svyy gur ragver 5 k 5 tevq jvgu oynpx fdhnerf. Nsgre nqqvat nyy gur oynpx fdhnerf sebz gur sbhe svtherf gung nyernql nccrne va dhrfgvba 1, gur fdhnerf gung erznva gb or svyyrq hc pna bayl or svyyrq hc ol gur 'Q' svther orybj gur yvar. )

Comment: @Alaiko Oh, that's really well spotted - very nice, thanks! :)

Comment: My doc just called - your diagnosis is right!! I don’t know if I should give you the tick just yet - maybe I’ll wait some time just so every question gets figured out ;)

Comment: @Jujustum Good to know :) Re checkmarking, I'd wait until it's fully solved to your satisfaction, get all the parts. When people make further suggestions you could always post a comment to let them know if their ideas are correct or not, and that might help us crack the whole thing eventually. (Or add additional subpuzzle-specific hints if it's taking us too long!)

Comment: I think I got question 10. Rot13(Jr unir n cnggrea bs 2 nqwnprag pryyf tbvat nebhaq gur pragre, 5 nqwnprag pryyf tbvat nebhaq gur pragre, 3 nqwnprag pryyf tbvat nebhaq gur pragre naq 1 pryy ba bhgfvqr gur prager. Fb jr'er zvffvat 4 nqwnprag pryyf tbvat nebhaq gur pragre juvpu pbeerfcbaqf gb bcgvba O - Avar, zrnavat gur yrggre jr jnag vf V.)

Comment: @Prim3numbah Looks promising to me, good work! I'll add once back from a Christmas gathering, thanks... Can't quite follow your #5 though, sorry, and not yet 100% convinced about your #7 but I could be persuaded there :)

Comment: Another idea for #10: rot13(Bayl gur frpbaq bcgvba unf fdhnerf plpyvat nebhaq gur pragre.) Simpler than Prim3numbah's, but it still works somewhat…

Comment: For questions 5 and 7, see Prim3numbah's answer (and comments on the answer). The logic on question 10 works, but wasn't the one intended! I'll add one last hint today ;)

Comment: Q10: rot13(Ahzore gur pryyf sebz 1 gb 7 va gur pnabavpny jnl, fhz gur pbeerfcbaqvat inyhrf bs gur oynpx pryyf naq bs gur bar pryy jvgu gur ahzore, cyhf gur ahzore vgfrys. Gur gbgny vf nyjnlf 28)

Comment: @TheFootprint Ah, in fact it's even simpler than that - just look at the other white cells and the number!

Comment: Well done! I think all the puzzles are now solved looking at all answers and comments. We're close to the checkmark! :D

Comment: I kinda already gave it away in the comments of Prim3numbah's answers, but here's a big hint for Q5: rot13(frr ubj rnpu bs gur svtherf unir n fznyy naq n ovt neebj? qba'g sbphf ba jurer gur yvggyr neebj vf, sbphf ba jurer vg vf cbvagvat)

Comment: @Jujustum Got there in the end! Couldn't see the 'second arrow' for the life of me in that particular one. Had to step back from the screen (quite literally) for that to click at last! Thanks for the mental runaround - a nice take on the IQ puzzle genre...

Comment: Congratulations and thanks for solving the puzzle!!

Answer (score 4):

Edit: Looks like I was wrong interpreting question 3 as the other possible one.

I know @Stiv already just answered but here are some explanations for 1,3,5,7,11 (didn't get 9) I had written down before.

**Question 1:**

> If we superimpose all four grids we get: 
>  
>  [image] 
>  so we can cleary see that the left-most option is what's missing to make the whole grid black. 
>  
>  [image] 
>  which represents the letter **D**.

**Question 3:**

> Each figure has a number of enclosed regions and they decrease from left to right. First have four, second have three, third have two and fourth have one enclosed region. Which means that the fifth must have zero enclosed regions which corresponds to the right-most option. 
>  [image] 
>  which represents the letter **V**.

**Question 5:**

> Here we need to focus on the hand with arrow. It always moves 135 degrees clockwise but the arrow then alternates between the three hands. It always end up in the left-most position after each rotation. The two other hands just follow and end up 45 degree and 90 degree, respectively, to the right of the *previously* arrowed hand. 
>  [image] 
>  So the correct answer is the right-most option: 
>  [image] 
>  which represents the letter **L**.

**Question 7: (not sure about this one, but I think it's correct)**

> Here I think we need to keep track of the positions of the dots. And then see how many of the dots in the second figure is in the same position as in the first figure. Then see how many of the dots in the third figure is in the same position as in the second figure, etc. Always comparing two adjacent figures. The numbers are always decreasing from left to right. 
>  [image] 
>  So the correct answer is the right-most option, since it's the only figure that follows the pattern. 
>  [image] 
>  which represents letter **V**

**Question 9: (no explanation)**

> 

**Question 11:**

> [image] 
>  We have an angle wich has two sides so we take the 2nd letter which is **N**. We have a square which has four sides so we take the 4th letter which is **A**. We have a circle which has one side so we take the 1th letter which is **C**. We have a triangle which have three sides so we take the 3rd letter which is **I**. 
>  Now of all the four options only hexagon fits this pattern because it has 6 sides and the 6th letter of hexagon is **O**. 
>  [image] 
>  So **O** is our letter here.

Comment: The logic behind Q5 you proposed isn’t the one intended, but it works perfectly! rot13(gur yvggyr neebj cbvagf gbjneqf gur fnzr qverpgvba nf gur ovt neebj va gur arkg svther). For Q7, this is very close: rot13(jura lbh pbhag gur qbgf gung fgnlf gur fnzr, nyfb pbhag gur juvgr qbgf gung fgnlf juvgr!)

Comment: For Q7, although the transformation from one cell to the other seems random, a common pattern is: rot13(Gur ahzore bs juvgr qbgf va n pryy qrgrezvarf ubj znal qbgf jvyy or bs n qvssrerag pbybe va gur arkg pryy). This pattern also yields the desired answer, and it is unique.

Comment: For Q5, that do you mean it always end up in the left-most position after each rotation?

Comment: what* do you mean*

Answer (score 3):

Q9: COUNT the sides of the white hexagons that do not have any common sides with the black hexagons, and then add to them the common sides that the white hexagons have in common among them and thus   you get number 19.  12 sides "on the air" and 7 common sides among only the white hexagons, gives us the number 19.

Comment: Nice find - this one definitely works and is straightforward to explain :)

Answer (score 0):

Q3. 1st figure has 4 divisions, 2nd has 3 , 3rd has 2, 1st has 1 , next should be 0 so the last option.

Q11. 1st figure is an angle with "N" , 2nd square with "A" , 3rd circle with C, 4th triangle with I so the correct answer is 2 (Triangle with A)

Comment: I think for 11, it should be rot13(gur urkntba jvgu "B". V guvax gur yrggre pbzrf sebz gur agu yrggre bs gur funcr, jurer a vf gur ahzore bs fvqrf/yvarf: nAtyr, fdhNer, Pvepyr, geVnatyr, urkntBa)

Answer (score 0):

For Q5, I found a different solution, that does not correspond though to the letter L that we want... If we add the 1st and 2nd picture, the 2 arrows create an angle of 135 degrees...If we add the 2nd and the 3rd, the 2 arrows  create an angle of 180 degrees, thus it is plus 45 degrees... if we add the 3rd and the 4th, we have again a plus 45 degrees angle from the previous one, thus it is 225 degrees... so the final one should be 270 degrees, and as a result the 2nd option from the left is the right one.